# Cual es la definición de ITERABLES e ITERADORES y sus diferencias [Python]

Tags: python, bucles, iteradores, conceptos

Recientemente me encontraba aprendiendo un poco de los ciclos o loops en python, tanto "while" como "for"; leyendo me surgieron ciertas dudas, que desembocaron en intentar comprender que son los Iterables y los Iteradores, además de cuales son las diferencias entre ambos, si es que las hay

Comment: en que lenguaje? bajo que conceptos aprendiste eso? la pregunta no esta mal.. pero un iterable tengo entendido que no es lo mismo segun el lenguaje...

Comment: @gbianchi listo bro ya lo edite, es en python

Answer (score 0):

**Iterable** es un objeto sobre el que se puede iterar, es decir, genera un iterador cuando se pasa al método `iter()`. **Iterador** es un objeto que se usa para iterar sobre un objeto iterable usando el método `__next __()`. Los iteradores tienen un método `__next__()`, que devuelve el siguiente elemento del objeto.

Ten en cuenta que todos los iteradores también son iterables, pero no todos los iterables son iteradores. Por ejemplo, una lista es iterable pero una lista no es un iterador. Se puede crear un iterador a partir de un iterable utilizando la función `iter()`. Para que esto sea posible, la clase de un objeto necesita un método `__iter__`, que devuelve un iterador, o un método `__getitem__` con índices secuenciales que comienzan con 0.

---

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código tenemos la función `iterable` que devolverá `True` si el objeto `obj` es iterable, caso contrario devolverá `False`.

```
def iterable(obj): 
try: 
    iter(obj) 
    return True
          
except TypeError: 
    return False
  
for element in [34, [4, 5],(4, 5), 
         {"a":4}, "dfsdf", 4.5]: 
                   
print(element, " is iterable : ", iterable(element))
```

Salida:

```
# 34 es iterable: falso
# [4, 5] es iterable: verdadero
# (4, 5) es iterable: verdadero
# {'a': 4} es iterable: verdadero
# dfsdf es iterable: verdadero
# 4.5 es iterable: False
```

Fuente de investigación: https://es.acervolima.com/python-diferencia-entre-iterable-e-iterador/

Comment: Si también pasé por esa pagina, pero la verdad es que no me quedo muy claro el concepto; agradezco igual la respuesta

Comment: Si aún no quedó claro con la explicación de Cris223511.dev, ¿Podrías mencionar qué parte(s) no has entendido? De esa forma él puede editar su respuesta u otro usuario escribir una nueva

Comment: La explicación sobre iterador no me parece del todo cierta, pues un iterador no tiene por que usarse para iterar un iterable. Dos ejemplos: los generadores y los iteradores del modulo itertools. Estos no dependen de ningún iterable. La definición correcta sería que un iterador es un objeto que tiene el método `__next__`, es decir, se puede usar la función next en él.

Answer (score 0):

#### Iterador

Si queremos entender que es un iterable, debemos primero entender que es un iterador. Un iterador es objeto el cual tiene un método `__next__` encargado de dar un valor (es decir, se puede usar la función `next` en él). Piensa en el concepto de iterador como una especie de lista, pero, en lugar de cargar todo en memoria, va generando el siguiente elemento sin guardar los anteriores siempre que se usa el método `__next__`.

Los iteradores también pueden implementar un método `__iter__` que generalmente devuelve al mismo iterable sin cambios. Esto es util para poder usar el iterador en un bucle for (que convierte el objeto pasado en iterador internamente).

Algo curioso de los iteradores, es que al generar elementos "en tiempo real" y no todos a la vez, pueden ser infinitos. Es decir, siempre obtendrás un valor de ellos y nunca verás venir de estos un error del tipo StopIteration. El modulo itertools, que volveré a mencionar más adelante, tiene iteradores infinitos.

#### Iterable

Sabiendo que es un iterador, podemos decir que un iterable es un objeto que se puede convertir en iterador, incluyendo a los propios iteradores. Para que un objeto sea iterable, debe tener un método `__iter__` que devuelva un iterador o un método `__getitem__` que acepte numeros de la misma forma que lo hace una lista (secuencial).

Un iterador no tiene por que venir de un iterable. Para ver ejemplos de iteradores que no provienen de ningún iterable, mira el modulo [itertools](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html)